# How do I prevent strings containing the word "yes" or "no" from printing out as true or false?

Tags: coldfusion

I'm currently setting a number of variables like so:

```
<cfset printPage = "YES">
```

Eventually, when I print these variables out, anything that I try to set to "YES" prints out as "true". Anything set to "NO", prints out as "false". I'm not opposed to using the `YesNoFormat` function. In fact I might end up using that function in this application, but in the mean time I would like to know if ColdFusion is actually storing the words "YES" and "NO" in memory, or if it is converting them to a boolean format behind the scenes.

If CF is storing my variables exactly the way that I declare them, how would I go about retrieving these variables as strings? If CF is changing the variables in some way, are there any special characters or keywords that I could use to force it to store the variables as strings?

Thank you to everyone that commented / answered. I did a little more experimenting and reading, and it seems that the serializeJSON function will automatically convert "Yes" to "true" and "No" to "false". I either need to deal with this problem in my javascript, or I can add a space in the affected properties to circumvent this behavior.

Comment: What do you mean by printing out?  This code, `x = "Yes";
writeoutput(x);
writedump(x);
` returns `Yes Yes`.

Comment: 1. Is it causing an actual problem or is this more of an educational question? 2. Immediately printing that variable would display "yes", so what exactly occurs in between defining it and *"...eventually.. print[ing] it out"*? CF performs implicit conversion in *many* cases. However, you would need to post a complete repro case for anyone to offer more specifics.

Answer (score 0):

You already know how to display the boolean value as "yes" or "no" (using `YesNoFormat()`). I don't think there is a way to force ColdFusion to store a variable a certain way. It just doesn't support that. I guess you could call out the Java type directly by using `JavaCast()`. I just don't see why you would want to go through that extra work for something like this. You can certainly research that a bit more if you like. [Here is a link to the document for JavaCast](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fbe.html).

Have a look at this document regarding [data types in ColdFusion](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec09af4-7ffa.html). I will post some of the relevant points from that document here but please read that page for more information.

> ColdFusion is often referred to as *typeless* because you do not assign types to variables and ColdFusion does not associate a type with the variable name. However, the data that a variable represents does have a type, and the data type affects how ColdFusion evaluates an expression or function argument. ColdFusion can automatically convert many data types into others when it evaluates expressions. For simple data, such as numbers and strings, the data type is unimportant until the variable is used in an expression or as a function argument.
>
> ColdFusion variable data belongs to one of the following type categories:
>
> **Simple** One value. Can use directly in ColdFusion expressions. Include numbers, strings, Boolean values, and date-time values.
>
> **Binary** Raw data, such as the contents of a GIF file or an executable program file.
>
> **Complex** A container for data. Generally represent more than one value. ColdFusion built-in complex data types include arrays, structures, queries, and XML document objects. You cannot use a complex variable, such as an array, directly in a ColdFusion expression, but you can use simple data type elements of a complex variable in an expression. For example, with a one-dimensional array of numbers called myArray, you cannot use the expression myArray * 5. However, you could use an expression myArray[3] * 5 to multiply the third element in the array by five.
>
> **Objects** Complex constructs. Often encapsulate both data and functional operations.

It goes on to say this regarding Data Types:

> **Data type notes**
>   Although ColdFusion variables do not have types, it is often convenient to use “variable type” as a shorthand for the type of data that the variable represents.
>
> ColdFusion provides the following functions for identifying the data type of a variable:
>
> - IsArray
> - IsBinary
> - IsBoolean
> - IsImage
> - IsNumericDate
> - IsObject
> - IsPDFObject
> - IsQuery
> - IsSimpleValue
> - IsStruct
> - IsXmlDoc
>
> ColdFusion also includes the following functions for determining whether a string can be represented as or converted to another data type:
>
> - IsDate
> - IsNumeric
> - IsXML

So in your code you could use something like `IsBoolean(printPage)` to check if it contains a boolean value. Of course that doesn't mean it is actually stored as a boolean but that ColdFusion can interpret it's value as a boolean.

Comment: Clearly you answered this question without reading so much as the first two sentences in the post.

Comment: HA!  indeed I did.  Sorry.